# How to use for loop and array to get 2 variables with similar value among 10 variables

Tags: php

There are 10 variables, maybe 1st variable and 3rd variable are the same value, and maybe 5th variables and 1st variable are the same value, do something when found any 2 variables that have the same value. I can do it in if statement but the code would be very long, how to shorten the code by for loop and array?

```
var q1 = 12;
var q2 = 13;
var q3 = 12;
var q4 = 22;
var q5 = 99;
var q6 = 100;
var q7 = 62;
var q8 = 99;
var q9 = 12;
var q10 = 99;

if (q1 == q2) || (q1 == q3) || (q1 == q4) || (q1 == q4).....{
       //do something
}

if (q2 == q3) || (q2 == q4) || (q2 == q4).....{
       //do something
}

if (q3 == q4) ||....
```

Comment: Put all values into an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead of individual variables.

Comment: if you already have a file with hundreds of variables and their values structured as shown in the question, you may read the file as text and create array by string manipulation. Or use text editor to create arrays out of the variables and their values.

Comment: Are you looking to check if a value already exists in a list? Simply put it all into an array and use `Array.indexOf` to figure out if it's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible approach. Put the variables in array and use nested loops:

```
<?php
$q1 = 12;
$q2 = 13;
$q3 = 12;
$q4 = 22;
$q5 = 99;
$q6 = 100;
$q7 = 62;
$q8 = 99;
$q9 = 12;
$q10 = 99;

$array = [$q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8, $q9, $q10];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
        if  ($array[$i] == $array[$j]) {
            echo 'q'.($i+1).', q'.($j+1).'<br>';
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
q1, q3
q1, q9
q3, q9
q5, q8
q5, q10
q8, q10
```

Comment: it seem loop non stop make the whole website lagging, how to make it loop only once?

Comment: @zac1987 Statements in the loops are executed 45 times (9 + 8 + ... + 1). For a single execution, this is not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged as PHP, here's a PHP solution, although the code you included doesn't look like PHP.

```
$arr = [$q1, $q2,$q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8, $q9, $q10];
foreach ($arr as $i=>$v){
 $ind = array_search($v, $arr);
 if($ind !== false && $ind !== $i){
  echo "Dupes ($ind, $i)";
 //do something
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array this becomes simple:

```
<?php

$values =
[
    'q1'=>'3',
    'q2'=>'1',
    'q3'=>'3',
    'q4'=>'5'
];

$has_dupes = array_unique($values)!==$values;

var_dump($has_dupes);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

If you need the keys for those that have matching values:

```
<?php
$matches = [];
foreach(array_count_values($values) as $key=>$count)
    if($count!==1)
        $matches[] = array_keys($values, $key);

var_export($matches);
```

Output:

```
array (
0 => 
array (
    0 => 'q1',
    1 => 'q3',
),
)
```